# What's the second set of parentheses mean after a require statement in Node.js?

Tags: javascript, node.js

I'm working with a coworkers code today and I saw something I've never seen before.

I understand the first part of the statement (require in the file clean.js).

But what's with the second set of parentheses?

```
require('./tasks/clean')('js', './dist/js')
```

Comment: Means a call to the unit that was required ... JavaScript is full of shortcuts

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Whatever is exported from `./tasks/clean` is a function, so it's just being invoked with `'js'` and `'./dist/js'` as parameters

It is equivalent to the following:

```
const clean = require('./tasks/clean');
clean('js', './dist/js');
```

Comment: Thanks. Sometimes all the short cuts get a but confusing to me.

Comment: Sure, why not? If you have a module that is just exporting a single function, it's fine to invoke it like this. If the function is going to be reused throughout a file, you could assign it to a variable and reference that. (Like my example)

Answer (score 6):

This syntax you are seeing is called [Function currying](https://www.sitepoint.com/currying-in-functional-javascript/), which is a popular technique in writing composable functions in the [Functional programming](http://eloquentjavascript.net/1st_edition/chapter6.html) paradigm. Currying and Functional programming are not new concepts, they have been around for decades, but Functional programming is starting to get really popular with the JavaScript community.

Currying basically lets you immediately invoke a function call from a function that returns a function.

Consider this function that returns a function:

```
 function foo(x) {
   console.log(x);
   return function(y) {
     console.log(y);
   }
 }
```

now when calling this function, you can now do this:

```
foo(1)(2);
```

which will output to the console:

```
1
2
```

So in the example that you posted, the `clean()` function must return a function that accepts two parameters, like this:

```
function clean(a) {
   return function(b, c) {
     console.log(a, b, c);
   }
}
```

which allows it to be called like this:

```
clean('foo')('bar', 'baz');
//=> 'foo' 'bar' 'baz'
```

This was a super basic example, but I hope this helps!