# What does mean "var router = require('./router/main')(app)"?

Tags: node.js, express

(I know that there is a similar question in stackoverflow, but I can't understand that question's comment..)

I'm Korean middle schooler.
So I am not good at English but Please help me.

I'm studying Node.js and Express.js by example codes.
This is example code which I'm looking at.

```
var express = require("express");
var app = express();
var bodyParser = require("body-parser");
var session = require("express-session");
var fs = require("fs");

app.set("views", __dirname + "/views");
app.set("view engine", "ejs");
app.engine("html", require("ejs").renderFile);

var server = app.listen(3000, function() {
    console.log("Express server has started on port 3000");
});

app.use(express.static("public"));

app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded());
app.use(session({
    secret: '@@SEC$$RET##',
    resave: false,
    saveUninitialized: true
}));

var router = require("./router/main")(app, fs)
```

I have understood majority of this code, but I cannot understand "(app, fs)" at last line.

What does that mean??
I'll appreciate your kindness if you help me .. ㅠㅠ

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What's the second set of parentheses mean after a require statement in Node.js?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42959510/whats-the-second-set-of-parentheses-mean-after-a-require-statement-in-node-js)

Answer (score 1):

It imports the router from that file. The router requires you to pass 2 parameters - the app and fs. It's the same as calling a regular function. Just here, it is importing the route and calling the function in one place.

Comment: wow thanks!! I reaaaaaaaaly understood that phrase!! Thanks for your explanation :D

Answer (score 1):

This means that `./router/main` module exports [factory function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Factory_(object-oriented_programming)) that accepts application instance and `fs` module as parameters and returns router instance that depends on these parameters, e.g.:

```
var express = require('express');

module.exports = (app, fs) => {
  var router = express.Router();
  // define router routes that make use of `app` and `fs`
  return router;
};
```

This way router factory function basically implements [dependency injection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dependency_injection) pattern.

`app` parameter is a common Express recipe to pass application instance to a router, while passing `fs` is unneeded. `fs` module could be imported directly in `./router/main` module, it doesn't benefit much from dependency injection.

Comment: Thanks for your explanation. I've understood majority of your comment, but I can't understand one thing. So you suggest me importing 'fs' module by passing fs module to ./router/main module?? Or Import fs module directly in router module? I'm not good at English.. ㅠㅠ

Comment: I'd suggest to import `fs` directly in './router/main' module in this case instead of passing it as argument. So it would be `var router = require("./router/main")(app)` in app module and `var fs = require('fs'); module.exports = (app) => {...}` in router module. That's how it's usually done in Node.

Comment: Thanks. I’ll use this nice tip from now on!